# How to change add() in Treeset

Tags: java

I want to implement union by using `add()` method in Treeset.

I write like this:

```
Set<Integer> union(Set<Integer> a, Set<Integer> b) {
    Treeset result = new Treeset();
    for(Integer i:a) {
        result.add(i);
    }
    for(Integer i:b) {
        result.add(i);
    }
    return result;
}
```

This is one of my Homework and our professor says we cannot use `add()` method, so, how I can use another way to implement it and get the same result?

Comment: I think you need to clarify the question with your professor. You cannot add to a set without using `add` or `addAll`.

Comment: @Joffrey You could be right. I guess we need the OP to clarify.

Comment: @PaulBoddington you can construct a new TreeSet from another collection. OP is not adding to an existing TreeSet, but building a new one.

Comment: @DiegoBasch Yes, but that only covers the first set, then you need to add the second set anyway.

Comment: @Joffrey There is a design-principle called Liskov substitution principle (LSP). So she is not allowed to change the behave of add.

Comment: @PeterRader I don't recall having mentioned such thing as modifying `add()`'s behaviour.

Comment: Anyway, the OP needs to clarify. Because as of now, the question clearly contradicts itself: *I want to implement union by using add() method in Treeset* but *we cannot use add() method*.

Comment: @Joffrey what I meant is that perhaps the point of the exercise was to create the union in a different structure and then turn that into a set. Otherwise it's a pointless restriction.

Answer (score 0):

Using `add` on individual elements is...slow.  It's also not quite the best style.

If I were doing this, I'd make use of `addAll` instead anyway, to add all of the things I care about at once.

```
public Set<Integer> union(final Set<Integer> left, final Set<Integer> right) {
    final Set<Integer> result = new TreeSet<>(left);
    result.addAll(right);
    return result;
}
```

**Be sure that you're not creating a raw type with your `TreeSet` instance.**  The above avoids that scenario; your code is (potentially) creating one, provided you meant `TreeSet` and not `Treeset`.